# Clickhouse altering materialized view's select

Tags: clickhouse

I have following setup:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS request_income_buffer (
    timestamp UInt64,
    timestamp_micro Float32,
    traceId Int64,
    host String,
    type String,
    service String,
    message String,
    caller String,
    context String
) ENGINE = Kafka('kafka:9092', 'request_income', 'group', 'JSONEachRow');

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS request_income
ENGINE = MergeTree(date, microtime, 8192) AS
    SELECT
        toDate(toDateTime(timestamp)) AS `date`,
        toDateTime(timestamp) as `date_time`,
        timestamp,
        timestamp_micro AS `microtime`,
        traceId,
        host,
        type,
        service,
        message,
        caller,
        context
    FROM
        request_income_buffer;
```

I want to add new column, ex. `ip` to `my request_income` table. 
According to docs in order to do so I will need to follow next steps:

1. Detach view to stop receiving messages from Kafka.

   > DETACH TABLE request_income;
2. Drop table that streams data from Kafka since Kafka engine doesn't support `ALTER` queries.

   > DROP TABLE request_income_buffer
3. Recreate table that streams data from Kafka with new field.

   > CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS request_income_buffer (
   >   timestamp UInt64,
   >   timestamp_micro Float32,
   >   traceId Int64,
   >   host String,
   >   ip String,
   >   type String,
   >   service String,
   >   message String,
   >   caller String,
   >   context String
   >   ) ENGINE = Kafka('kafka:9092', 'request_income', 'group', 'JSONEachRow');
4. According to this [post](https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/issues/1226) update .inner table of the detached materialized view

   > ALTER TABLE `.inner.request_income` ADD COLUMN ip String AFTER host;
5. According to post from above update view's select query
6. Attach view

   > ATTACH TABLE request_income

Question is how to update view's select query?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So it appears the way to update materialized view's select query is as follows:

1. Get path to views metadata

   > SELECT metadata_path FROM system.tables WHERE name = 'request_income';
2. Use your favorite text editor to modify view's sql. In my case edited sql will look like

   > ATTACH MATERIALIZED VIEW request_income (
   >       date Date,
   >       date_time DateTime,
   >       timestamp UInt64,
   >       microtime Float32,
   >       traceId Int64,
   >       host String,
   >       **ip String,**
   >       type String,
   >       service String,
   >       message String,
   >       caller String,
   >       context String ) ENGINE = MergeTree(date, microtime, 8192) AS SELECT
   >       toDate(toDateTime(timestamp)) AS date,
   >       toDateTime(timestamp) AS date_time,
   >       timestamp,
   >       timestamp_micro AS microtime,
   >       traceId,
   >       host,
   >       **ip**,
   >       type,
   >       service,
   >       message,
   >       caller,
   >       context FROM default.request_income_buffer
3. Attach modified view back

   > ATTACH TABLE request_income;

Comment: How would this be influenced if the tables are of the `ReplicatedMergeTree` family?

Answer (score 3):

Try this out:

1. `DETACH TABLE request_income;`
2. `` ALTER TABLE `.inner.request_income` ADD COLUMN ip String AFTER host; ``
3. ```
   ATTACH MATERIALIZED VIEW request_income 
   ENGINE = MergeTree(date, microtime, 8192) AS
    SELECT
        toDate(toDateTime(timestamp)) AS `date`,
        toDateTime(timestamp) as `date_time`,
        timestamp,
        timestamp_micro AS `microtime`,
        traceId,
        host,
        ip,
        type,
        service,
        message,
        caller,
        context
    FROM
        request_income_buffer;
   ```

Comment: I'm doing this, but reattached materialized view does not contain the new column. What's wrong?

Comment: It looks like `TO` materialized views (with explicit target table) work differently. I see ATTACH for them work incorrectly. However, for them you can just DROP and then CREATE them again.