# How to alter/change Materialized View TTL in the Clickhouse?

Tags: clickhouse

I have a materialized view:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW reporting_device_raw_data
ENGINE = MergeTree()
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(ts)
ORDER BY (device_id, ts)
TTL ts + INTERVAL 3 MONTH
AS SELECT
    device_id,
    ts,
    value
FROM reporting_device_raw_data_null;
```

I tried to:

```
ALTER TABLE reporting_device_raw_data MODIFY TTL ts + INTERVAL 12 MONTH;
```

But got erorr:

```
DB::Exception: Alter of type 'MODIFY TTL' is not supported by storage MaterializedView.
```

What are possible workarounds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check `show create database ....` for database engine.

Ordinary database:

```
ALTER TABLE ".inner.reporting_device_raw_data" MODIFY TTL ts + INTERVAL 12 MONTH;
```

Atomic database:

```
select uuid from system.tables where name = 'reporting_device_raw_data';
ALTER TABLE ".inner_id.{uuid from prev. select}" MODIFY TTL ts + INTERVAL 12 MONTH;
```

Comment: I attempted this on my db and if I `show create table my_index` I see the old value for TTL, but `show create table ".inner.my_index"` shows the new TTL value.  Is there another step I need to take to sync or anything?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50622488/clickhouse-altering-materialized-views-select/50624243#50624243 looks like a duplicate and has a bit more info on the need to detach and re-attach the materialized view

Comment: @jeremy TTL in MV does not matter. Check this https://den-crane.github.io/Everything_you_should_know_about_materialized_views_commented.pdf

Comment: So if I'm understanding right, the materialized view is putting data in the real table ".inner.[myindextable]" and as long as the TTL is correct on the .inner table I will be okay?  How does this work with a cluster of databases?  Do I need to run this on each node in the cluster or can I do "ON CLUSTER x"?

Comment: @jeremy I dare you to use `TO` materialized view syntax notation. https://den-crane.github.io/Everything_you_should_know_about_materialized_views_commented.pdf

Comment: Appreciate the help!!